# Storing PHP variable with session (or cookies)?

Tags: php, jquery, session, variables, store

I've been looking into using a variable to let visitors choose if embedded Youtube videos autoplay or not. I've been thinking about using a link like `myurl.com/?autoplay=0` to stop autoplay and `1` to enable it again. I read a bit about sessions (don't know if that's the best practice here though since I'm new to PHP), but couldn't quite get it to work after loading a second video. If anyone could point out my error(s) and help me, *or suggest a better way to solve it*, I'd be most grateful.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['autoplay']=0
?>

<!-- content here removed for readability -->
        <button class="randomizerButton" data-href="data.php">Randomize</button>
        <hr>

        <div id="results">
        <?php include('data.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('button.randomizerButton').click(function(){
                    scriptUrl = $(this).attr('data-href');
                    $.post(scriptUrl, function(response){
                        $('#results').html(response);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**data.php**

```
if ($_SESSION['autoplay'] == "0"){
    $autoplayVar = 0;
}
else{
    $autoplayVar = 1;
    }

echo ($autoplayVar);

echo ('<br>');


echo('<iframe id="ytplayer" width="557" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/0wLljngvrpw&autoplay='.$autoplayVar.'" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at it like a shopping cart,
when you add items to your basket you want them to be saved even if you close the browser, or come back after a while.

**Cookies are Similar to Session Variables ** in PHP, **the only difference** that sets both apart is that **Sessions are handled and saved in the Server** 
(Usually being used to test Login State)

While **Cookies are saved in the Client's Browser** (Usually for less important stuff like preferences).
look at cookies!
 **[Cookies by PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)**

Cookies let you save some **NON-Important** data. 
You can set the **Auto-Play**, or the Background-Theme, **(Even the remember me? Done with Cookies!)** with cookies.

```
setcookie("autoplay", $value);
```

And to get back the data :

```
$Does_he_want_autoplay = $_COOKIE['autoplay'];
```

You can find all and more in the link I gave.

Comment: Thanks, that's mighty informative! I took a quick look and ran a basic example, this seems very useful and fit my needs just fine for this purpose I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use

`myurl.com/?autoplay=0`

This `autoplay` variable will be accessible via `$_GET['autoplay']`

This code will work with the URL above.

```
<?php
$autoplayVar = $_GET['autoplay'];

echo ($autoplayVar);

echo ('<br>');


echo('<iframe id="ytplayer" width="557" height="315" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/0wLljngvrpw&autoplay='.$autoplayVar.'" 
frameborder="0"></iframe>');
?>
```

If you want to store a `$_SESSION` variable to control the start, you need a way for the user to save the state of the autoplay.  You can implement it so that when a person goes to `myurl.com/?autoplay=0` the first time, it store the `0` state for the rest of the session.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['autoplay'] = $_GET['autoplay'];
echo ($autoplayVar);

echo ('<br>');


echo('<iframe id="ytplayer" width="557" height="315" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/0wLljngvrpw&autoplay='.$_SESSION['autoplay'].'" 
frameborder="0"></iframe>');
```

Comment: @hawaiianchimp Thanks for the input, I tried your solutions but neither seem to carry the `$_SESSION['autoplay']` state after refresh or when going back to a normal `myurl.com/` url?

Comment: Every page must include the `session_start();` at the top of the page, so if you go to `myurl.com/` without `session_start()` then the `$_SESSION` variable will not be available. Try placing `echo $_SESSION['autoplay']` after you have put `session_start();` on every page to see what it prints.

Comment: @hawaiianchimp Yeah, I put `<?php
session_start();` at the top of both **index.php** and **data.php** but still no result. Works fine for linking `myurl.com?autoplay=1` but does not remember the state after clicking the button, simply displaying blank I'm afraid.